# Use PHP and JSON to get the Column Name from SQLSRV

Tags: php, jquery, sql, json, google-visualization

Below is the code I use and it works but only gets the rows and not columns, I am importing the data to a Google Chart Tools chart and it uses the first row as the colunm information making it inaccurate.

Is there a way to get the column name and add it to the array?

```
<?php
    require "connectioninfo.php";

    if ($databaseConnection == false)
    {
        echo "<p>Database connection failed...</p>";
    }
    else
    {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM avTable";
    $statement = sqlsrv_query($databaseConnection, $query);
    echo $statement;
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($statement))
        {
            $rows[] = array($row['BusinessName'],$row['Hygiene']);
        } 

        $dataTable = json_encode($rows,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

    sqlsrv_free_stmt($statement); 
    }
    sqlsrv_close($databaseConnection);      
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($statement))
{
    $arr = array();
    for($row as $key => $value){
        // $key is your column name
        // $value is the value of $row[$key]

        // Copy data on clean array...
        $arr[$key] = $value;
    }

    // Process on column name...

    $rows[] = $arr;
}
```

**EDIT :**

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.yourTableName')
```

or better you can obtain this information and much, much more by querying the [Information Schema views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933204%28SQL.80%29.aspx).

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME='yourTable'
```

After that, you will retrieve $result["COLUMN_NAME"], $result["DATA_TYPE"], $result["TABLE_NAME"], $result["CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH"], and so on...

You'll have a first query to determine column names, then a second query with all datas.

Comment: it doesn't load up the webpage is just white.

Comment: it is not a working code... Just to show you a possible solution to your problem. You have to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: also I want to ADD the column name to the array I get form my code. Surely I can do something with the $key to my current code like $key['BusinessName'] + $row['BusinessName'] to make it include the column name?

Comment: In your example, $key = "BusinessName", and $key['BusinessName'] is empty (does not exists...) Sry, I don't get what you want to do... Please try to explain me

Comment: I have a database which has values which I need to get and put into a JavaScript chart. The code I posted works but it does not use the columns names for the values but the rows instead as the sqlsvr_fetch_array code gets the rows and not the column name. So what I need is each column and its data type to be passed along with the rows to make the table.

so BusinessName would be Column name: BusinessName, Column Type: String and Row Data BusinessNames.

and Hygiene would be the same but the Hygiene column and data.

Comment: Using the select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='yourTable' would I need two while loops then? or would that output every value within the schema, I am a bit confused with the I will retrieve the $result. Surely that is what my $query already does but only for the data right?

I am sorry if I am asking stupid questions, I think after getting as far as I have done, my brain is a bit mixed up

Comment: yes it's exactly that, try to run the schema query and you'll see what you get, I think that you need...

Comment: Ok, I shall try and run the select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME='yourTable' inplace of my select * from avtable once I have gotten some rest, thank you very much for the help, I will keep this open until I have gotten it working and I hope I can count on your help in the future.

Comment: no problem, and when your problem will be resolved, please check my answer ;)

Comment: I tried replacing the $query = "select * from avtable"; with the line you gave but that does not seem to work, how do I access each component and then encode them into one string?